# How to deal with multiple Fields like Telephone Numbers in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I think this is a classical SQL problem but I was not able to find any hint on the internet.

My database tables are:

```
Table User:
ID  UserName Adress
1   Uwe      No 1
2   user2    No 2
3   name3    No 3


Table Tel:
ID  telNumber user_id
1   123       1
2   234       1
3   123       2
4   567       1
5   900       3
6   800       3
7   111       1
```

With this select:

```
SELECT user.UserName, tel.telNumber, user.Adress
FROM [user] INNER JOIN tel ON user.ID = tel.user_id;
```

I will get:

```
UserName  Tel       Adress
---------------------------
Uwe       123       No 1      
Uwe       234       No 1      
user2     123       No 2      
Uwe       567       No 1      
name3     900       No 3      
name3     800       No 3      
Uwe       111       No 1      
----------------------------
```

What I'am looking for is something like this now:

```
Name: Uwe
Tel1: 123
Tel2: 234
Tel3: 567
Tel4: 111
Adress: No 1


Name: name3
Tel1: 900
Tel2: 800
Adress: No 3
```

How can I get this result? How I have to adapt my SQL statement, that I get a comfortable way to catch it by PHP?

Comment: Just order your existing join query by name or user_id, and then just loop through the results. The output you want should be generated by your PHP code, not the database. It'll be a lot easier if you sort the query by user, but apart from that you're already on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `group_concat` with `group by` to get each user with their phone numbers. You then could use explode, or some other function to split out the phone numbers and iterate over them. Example:

```
SELECT u.UserName, group_concat(t.telNumber) as numbers, u.Adress
FROM user as u
INNER JOIN tel as t 
ON u.ID = t.user_id
group by u.ID
```

SQL Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dca9b/3

PHP implementation would be something like:

```
<?php
$numers = array('User1' => '1', 'User2' => '123,456');
foreach($numers as $user => $num){
    echo $user . PHP_EOL;
    if(strpos($num, ',') === FALSE) {
        echo 'Tel1:' . $num .PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $nums = explode(',', $num);
        foreach($nums as $key => $temp){
            echo 'Tel' . ($key + 1) . ':' .  $temp .PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/OE3IA

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb: *don't mix presentation data with logic*.

You don't in fact *need* an SQL query to return the sequence number for a common-theme list of records. This detail is best left to the application layer, i.e. your PHP code. Let your PHP code "know" when it's listing telephone numbers for a given user (which should be trivial) and present them in an enumerated fashion like you've shown (pseudo code):

```
for each user:
    i = 0
    for each 'user' phone number:
        i++
        show phone number (i)
    next
next
```

It is (generally) less important to know which telephone is in which position than knowing you've got them all right for a user.